TestRail Integration with Selenium : TestRail API returned HTTP 400("One of Status ID, Assigned To or Comment is required")
I am facing issue while integrating Selenium with TestRail. I get the below error message while updating the status to TestRail.
The script was successfully executed. Just that Results are not posted in to TestRail.
Exception:
com.gurock.testrail.APIException: TestRail API returned HTTP 400("One of Status ID, Assigned To or Comment is required")
at com.gurock.testrail.APIClient.sendRequest(APIClient.java:296) 
at com.gurock.testrail.APIClient.sendPost(APIClient.java:132) 
at com.qa.testrailmanager.TestRailManager.addResultsForTestCase(TestRailManager.java:47) 
at TestBase.BaseClass.addResultsToTestRail(BaseClass.java:26) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)

Test Code:
 public class TestRailManager {

    public static String TEST_RUN_ID = "1"; //1 is the testrail TestRun ID.
    
    public static String TEST_RAIL_USERNAME = "iiii@gmail.com";
    public static String TEST_RAIL_PASSWORD = "XXXXX";
    
    public static String TEST_RAIL_URL = "https://sr156.testrail.io/";
    
    public static int TEST_CASE_PASS_STATUS = 1;
    public static int TEST_CASE_FAIL_STATUS = 5; 
    
   
    public static void addResultsForTestCase(String testcaseID, int status, String error) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, APIException
    {
        String testRunID = TEST_RUN_ID;
            
        APIClient client = new APIClient(TEST_RAIL_URL);
        client.setUser(TEST_RAIL_USERNAME);
        client.setPassword(TEST_RAIL_PASSWORD);
        
        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("Status_id", status);
        data.put("Comment", "This TC is executed via Selenium"+error);
        client.sendPost("add_result_for_case/"+testRunID+"/"+testcaseID,data);
    
In BaseClass I added,

    @AfterMethod
    public void addResultsToTestRail(ITestResult result) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, APIException
    {
        
        
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            //if pass, dont provide Error
            System.out.println("PASS");
            
            TestRailManager.addResultsForTestCase(testCaseID, TestRailManager.TEST_CASE_PASS_STATUS, "");
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            System.out.println("Fail");
            TestRailManager.addResultsForTestCase(testCaseID, TestRailManager.TEST_CASE_FAIL_STATUS,"The TC,"+result.getName()+ " : FAILED");
        }
    }

}

I was expecting that results will be updated in TestRail after Selenium Script execution.
